# How to create a background job in AEM as a Cloud?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I want to create a daily background job to be executed by AEM.
I read an aem document and apache sling official site, and I thought I need two classes.

- a service class that register the job to JobManager.
- a consumer class that do the job.

So I tried these code, but my job was not executed.

service class

```
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobManager;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.JobBuilder.ScheduleBuilder;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component
public class MyJobService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobService.class);
    
    @Reference
    private JobManager jobManager;

    public static final String JOB_TOPIC = "my/sample/jobtopic";

    public void startScheduledJob() {
        ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = jobManager.createJob(JOB_TOPIC).schedule();
       
        scheduleBuilder.hourly(9, 0); // execute daily at AM9:00
        if (scheduleBuilder.add() == null) {
            logger.error("myjobservice error");
        }
    }
}
```

job consumer class

```
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.Job;
import org.apache.sling.event.jobs.consumer.JobConsumer;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    service = JobConsumer.class,
    property = {
        JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS + "=my/sample/jobtopic"
    }
)
public class MyJobConsumer implements JobConsumer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobConsumer.class);
    @Override
    public JobResult process(Job job) {
        String topic = job.getTopic();
        logger.info("this message is from myjobconsumer. topic is " + topic);
        return JobResult.OK;
    }  
}
```

Do I need another class or some configurations? Does My code have something wrong?

Comment: Do you call the startScheduledJob method somewhere?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Thank you for comment. I misunderstood that it's kind a auto thing. Could you tell me where to call this type of method in normal AEM usage?

Comment: You can only call it from other code but you can call it on startup of the component.

Comment: @watopin did you manage to get this working, it seems to be calling it twice at the scheduled time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate a method with @Activate it will be called when the component starts.

@Activate
public void startScheduledJob()

I guess you want your job to run on startup.
Another option would be to let MyJobService be a servlet and call it from outside.

Comment: Thank you very much. My job is executed. but my job is executed twice(or more) each time. Is it Queue problem?

Comment: Possibly your component is activated more than once (can happen easily in AEM). 
How do you really want to activate your job? Should it run on startup or on a different trigger?

Comment: No matter how many times startScheduledJob() method called(because this method just schedule), I want my job done(jobconsumer's process method) just once a day.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried commons scheduler, but it doesn't work in AEM as a Cloud environment. On local SDK it was OK.